# update one table based on condition on other table

Tags: mysql

my tables look like this.

[tables photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2FVq.png)

If approved_by_asm =1 and approved_by_rsm=0 then mystatus column should be PENDING

else if approved_by_asm =0 and approved_by_rsm=1 then mystatus column should be PENDING

else if approved_by_asm =0 and approved_by_rsm=0 then mystatus column should be PENDING

else if  approved_by_asm =1 and approved_by_rsm=1 then mystatus column should be APPROVED

else mystatus column should be DECLINED. How to achieve this using SQL, I'm using MySQL as database.

here is my code:

```
create view view1 

as 

select *


 case 

  when approved_by_asm = 0 and approved_by_rsm = 0 THEN 'PENDING'

  when approved_by_asm = 0 and approved_by_rsm = 1 THEN 'PENDING'

  when approved_by_asm = 1 and approved_by_rsm = 0 THEN 'PENDING'

  when approved_by_asm = 1 and approved_by_rsm = 1 THEN 'APPROVED'

  else 'DECLINED' 

  end mystatus 

from loan_coooler ;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) - Incidentally, to my mind, VIEWs serve almost no useful purpose in MySQL. Also, I don't understand under what conditions mystatus could ever be declined.

Comment: Code looks good to me - what do you think is wrong with it and what does the title have to do with the rest of the question?

Comment: Could you be more specific, where the second table is coming from and how it is related. If it is all in one table use **UPDATE loan_coooler 
SET mystatuis = ** and then your case till the end and run it

Comment: I get this error when i run it: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case

  when approved_by_asm = 0 and approved_by_rsm = 0 THEN 'PENDING'

  ' at line 8

Comment: That's because you're missing a comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following which, if nothing else, demonstrates the same logic with less typing...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(a TINYINT NULL,b TINYINT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(NULL,NULL),
(0,NULL),
(NULL,0),
(1,NULL),
(NULL,1),
(0,0),
(1,0),
(0,1),
(1,1);

SELECT *
     , -- AND NOTE THE COMMA!!! 
       CASE WHEN a+b < 2 THEN 'pending' WHEN a+b = 2 THEN 'approved' ELSE 'declined' END x 
  FROM my_table;
+------+------+----------+
| a    | b    | x        |
+------+------+----------+
| NULL | NULL | declined |
|    0 | NULL | declined |
| NULL |    0 | declined |
|    1 | NULL | declined |
| NULL |    1 | declined |
|    0 |    0 | pending  |
|    1 |    0 | pending  |
|    0 |    1 | pending  |
|    1 |    1 | approved |
+------+------+----------+
```

Comment: it solved my problem, what is the use of COMMA?

Comment: A comma is used (inter alia) to separate columns in a SELECT statement.